# iPad - Popover with table view - show details on tap of cell

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

In my iPad application, on click of a button "Show" it will show 7 cells which has "Favorites".
On taping that, I want to push a new table view controller which shows the list of favorite items. But I want the new table view pushed in the same pop over without closing it. Also it will have "back" button on the top left to go back if needed.

It is something like "book marks" button click in "Amazon Kindle".
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you got a few options

1- Use a UINavigationController as the root of the view hiarchy in the popover, then just use that to push and pop view controllers as needed

2- Just use a UIViewController and add or remove the subviews as need (use a toolbar for your back button)

I would probably go for option 1...

Daniel